# Process system is not responding?

Tags: system-error

I have got an Archos 70 and today while playing a game I got an error. After that system is restarting automatically and it gives following error.

> 'process system is not responding'

And then it restarts again and so on. Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: I have an archos70 and i have the same issue today. I cant turn it off. it restarts itself again and again. While it starts im pressing the volume + button but no recovery mode appears.
What can i do now. It seems i have to wait until the battery discharges, or is there another method to get to the recovery mode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
I too have an Archos 70 and had this same issue.
All I did was to turn it off, then reboot it in"Recovery Mode".

- Turn off the device and wait 10 seconds.

  - Press and hold the volume + button while powering on the device.
  - Keep the volume + pressed until the Recovery mode starts (white screen).
  - To move from one option to another, use the volume buttons. To select an option, press the
    ON/OFF button.
    Then proceeded to run "Check Disk".

All returned to normal after the tablet was then rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a post on another forum](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=30120&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=0) regarding this same problem on an Archos 5.  Here's a post that seems to explain a workaround for this problem:

> Low memory conditions do crazy things
>   with Android on the 5A. Poor memory
>   management yielding: Increased
>   Response time, Extended Slowdowns,
>   Freezing, Reboot, and the like.
>
> To make this even worse, the Android
>   Archos 5 usually gives us no warning.
>   What to do!?!
>
> Turn on Settings>Sound &
>   display>Audible selection
>
> Then you get a "click" each time you
>   tap a screen selection.
>
> The Warning: Not Hearing the Click
>   After a Tap
>
> The Action: Wait until you hear the
>   tap "click".
>
> As Android matures with better memory
>   management this will go away. Maybe
>   Google with fix it this year,
>   especially if Android devices get more
>   market penetration.

I'd give this a shot and see if you end up seeing this error less frequently.  The whole thread makes it sound like these Archos devices have issues with memory management, leading to a crash when the RAM gets full.